# What is max video recording length?

Tags: video

I discovered the that iPhone 4 has a max video recording length of 50 mins due to some limitation built into the phone. Is Windows Phone similarly limited?

Comment: I can't dig up the information. I am recording now. i will let you know when/if it makes me stop :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to record 43 minutes before it stopped, and that was due to lack of storage space. I have over 9GB of free space, so presumably the only limitation is the free space you have on your phone. I can't be sure of this though. YMMV

Comment: not clear from your answer, the video you produced was 9GB?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have 9.13GB of space and that translated to about 43 minutes of video (at 720p)

Answer (score 5):

I'm agree with @Joe, 
But don't forget your have two limitations, your mobile free space (+1 @Joe), and your battery level!

If you have 1TO free Space, if your max battery recording for 1 hour, you don't recording more than 1 hour...

Comment: true, but you can connect an external battery to increase battery life

Comment: that depends no? 
for sample, if battery is not take off in your phone, ( lumia 800 ... ) the same solution is connect your phone for charging this. But, for other phone ( when we take off the battery )  I'm agree with you (@Michael + 1) .

Comment: I have a Mini USB recharger that allows my phone to recharge while I'm using it: http://118.139.176.118/gpbatteries/site/corpsite/INT/images/MasterProduct640/Spec/GPXPB05.pdf